# Cannot print to command line in sql plus

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I have a procedure created in an external file as

```
create or replace procedure emp_select
is
begin
    dbms_output.put_line('Hello World');
end;
/
```

It is run in sqlplus using

```
@ /pathtofile
```

It gives `procedure created`

But `exec emp_select;` only says `procedure executed successfully`, but no output on screen

Comment: Did you run `set serveroutput on;` first?

Comment: That was the issue. set serveroutput on; fixed it .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run this in SQL*Plus first:

```
set serveroutput on;
```